# Unable to define external URL for MvcSiteMapProvider with DynamicNode

Tags: url, mvcsitemapprovider

I've been pondering this problem for hours now, and it looks to me that while the XML site map functionality was updated to accept external URLs with the URL attribute, that feature was not extended to dynamic definitions via DynamicNode.

We have several applications that share a menu, and thus we need a single definition for these menu items, each pointing to one of our applications in the intranet.  We currently use (for ASP.NET) a custom site map that requires the XML files be deployed to each application, and I want the MVC implementation to read the items dynamically - probably from a database.

Since DynamicNode does not have a URL property, it clearly requires that the path be virtual and based upon the other properties (controller, action, routes). I tried implementing a UrlResolver to look at "action" for "HTTP", which worked, and I returned the URL unchanged.  However, I receive the dreaded

> "http://site.com/App is not a valid virtual path."

error. It appears the change introduced by the author in 3.1.0 for the XML property did not translate to the dynamic equivalent.  Can anyone help me?  Here is the code I wrote to extend the default classes.  This code is executed and works fine.  Sometime after ResolveUrl returns my HTTP, the failure occurs, so I guess I'm either missing something or it cannot be done.

```
   public class DynamicSiteMapNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase
    {
        override public IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
        {
            var nodes = new List<DynamicNode>();
            nodes.Add(new DynamicNode
                {
                    Key = "Dynamic1",
                    Title = "Dynamic One!",
                    Action = "http://my.site.com/MyApp"

                });
            return nodes;

        }
    }

    public class FlexibleSiteMapUrlResolver: DefaultSiteMapNodeUrlResolver
    {
        public override string ResolveUrl(MvcSiteMapNode mvcSiteMapNode, string area, string controller, string action, IDictionary<string, object> routeValues)
        {
            // when action value is clearly a web site url, simply accept it.
            if (action.Substring(0, 5).ToLower() == "http:")
            {
                return action;
            }
            return base.ResolveUrl(mvcSiteMapNode, area, controller, action, routeValues);
        }
    }
```

5/15/2013: Is there nobody who can help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in version 4 - the URL property has been added to the DynamicNode object and works the same as it does everywhere else.

Version 4 was released a couple of weeks ago and is available on the [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=mvcsitemapprovider).

Comment: Thanks much.  I updated a couple days ago, so I'll give it another shot.  When/if it works out, I'll tag this as the answer.

Comment: I just confirmed the problem is gone.  I also notice there are improved extensions for dynamic menus - Excellent!